# Assign site template to organization site programmatically in liferay 6.1.0

Tags: liferay-6

I have created user & organization pragmatically using addUser() & addOrganization() methods respectively.

I am also able to add users to this organization using addOrganizationUsers() method.

Now I have created a site template from liferay control panel.

As we know , we can create a site for organization, and while creating a site we have options to select a site template for public & private pages.

As we know .
Public page - Visible to members + non members
Private page - Visible to only members.

So I want to create a organization site with private pages only so it will be seen by only organization member.

```
OrganiztionLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization(
    long userId, long parentOrganizationId, String name, String type,
    boolean recursable, long regionId, long countryId, int statusId,
    String comments, boolean site, ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

Using above method , by specifying boolean site value 'true' a site will get created.

Now I want to add a site template to this organization site pragmatically which I have created from control panel.

So is there any API to add site template to any site of organization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no public API for it.

Use LayoutSetPrototypeLocalServiceUtil to get the ID for the SiteTemplate. To get the SiteTemplate by name you'll have to either use a dynamicQuery or iterate over the result of LayoutSetPrototypeLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutSetPrototypes(-1, -1)

Then invoke applyLayoutSetPrototypes of SitesUtil in the context of the portal.

```
MethodKey methodKey = new MethodKey("com.liferay.portlet.sites.util.SitesUtil","applyLayoutSetPrototypes", Group.class, long.class, long.class, ServiceContext.class);
PortalClassInvoker.invoke(false, methodKey, organization.getGroup(), publicLayoutSetId, privateLayoutSetId, serviceContext);
```

Specify -1 for publicLayoutSetId.

An Admin has to be logged in to perform this action.
To perform this action on startup or in the background a new ServiceContext would be needed.

Something like the following

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setSignedIn(false);
// set the following to an admin user / company or default user
User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getDefaultUser(companyId); // or any user that has the permissions
serviceContext.setUserId(user.getUserId());
serviceContext.setCompanyId(companyId);
```

And most likely you also have to setup the ThreadPermissionChecker

```
PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(user.getUserId());
PermissionChecker adminPermissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(user, false);
PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(adminPermissionChecker);
```

Don't forget to reset the permission checker in a final block otherwise the same permission checker might be used for other requests on the same thread.

Comment: Hello Schup thank you for such a valuable feedback. now I am able to get site template value and also able to pass correct parameters to this PortalClassInvoker.invoke()method, but as I also noticed that to perform this method Admin needs to be logged in, so Can you tel me how cam pro-grammatically login and  perform this method and & then logout also pro-grammatically?

Comment: I've updated the answer with information around creating a new ServiceContext and setting it as ThreadLocal variable.